# Android Wear: Cannot Resolve Image Reference

Tags: android, wear-os

Probably a stupid question here but I just started programming in Android so bear with me.

https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/ca2d0a9f79b902b19a65

I'm following this project to implement a GridViewPager on my Android Wear application. It works fine, only the background images I'm trying to use are not displaying. It only displays a black screen.

The issue is this getBackground() method, the imageReference in particular.

```
 public ImageReference getBackground(int row, int col) {
            SimplePage page = ((SimpleRow)mPages.get(row)).getPages(col);
            return ImageReference.forDrawable(page.mBackgroundId);
    }
```

The tutorial shows that an Image Reference should be returned however I am getting build errors saying that ImageReference cannot be resolved. So would I have to create a class or interface for ImageReference? Or do you set an attribute on the images themselves?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 1.1 of the Wearable Support Library (which [FragmentGridPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/FragmentGridPagerAdapter.html) is part of), the methods have changed quite a bit: they no longer use any sort of `ImageReference` class - the new method, [getBackgroundForPage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/FragmentGridPagerAdapter.html#getBackgroundForPage(int,%20int)), simply returns a `Drawable`.

Comment: Cheers Ian. That makes sense now.